# Select dataframe rows with ambiguous value assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Problem with identifying ambiguous variable matches. I'm looking through a database and want to find companies where an identifier changes over the whole observation period. I also have another identifier that is permanent.

If the table would look like this:

```
ID1  ID2

1111  1
1111  1
1111  1
1112  1
1112  1
1112  1
4444  2
4444  2
4444  2
```

I would like to get a simple output similar to this:

```
ID1   ID2

1111  1
1112  1
```

Many thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first identify `ID2`s with more than 1 ID1 (with `transform('nunique')`) then we drop duplicates.

```
df[df.groupby('ID2').ID1.transform('nunique').gt(1)].drop_duplicates()
#    ID1  ID2
#0  1111    1
#3  1112    1
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df = df.drop_duplicates()
df[df.duplicated(subset=['ID2'], keep=False)]
```

Out:

```
|   | ID1  | ID2 |
|---|------|-----|
| 0 | 1111 | 1   |
| 3 | 1112 | 1   |
```